# Relation between cross entropy and conditional entropy

Tags: optimization, conditional-probability, information-theory, coding-theory, entropy

Is there a relationship between cross-entropy and conditional entropy between two categorical variables?

Definition of cross-entropy:
$$
H_X(Y) = -\sum_{x} P(X=x)\log P(Y=x)
$$

Definition of conditional entropy:
$$ \small
H(Y|X) = -\sum_{(x,y)} P(X=x,Y=y)\log P(Y=y|X=x)
$$

Here, $X$ and $Y$ are defined over the same finite probability space --- i.e., the possibilities for $x$ and $y$ are a finite shared set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$.

In an optimization problem, can we minimize cross-entropy instead of minimizing conditional entropy? If so, can we derive the relationship between these two?

Comment: what does $(x,y)$ mean? If no constrain between $x$ and $y$ then $H_X(Y)=\sum_y\log(y)$ which is infinite if there are infinitely many $y$'s. I think you means to put something else in place of $p(y)$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the spaces of $X$ and $Y$ in the post, which are finite and shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little or no relationship. The cross entropy relates only to the marginal distributions, (the dependence between $X$ and $Y$ do not matter) while the conditional entropy relates to the joint distribution (dependence between $X$ and $Y$ is essential).

In general [you could write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy)

$$\begin{align}
H_X(Y) &= H(X) + D_{KL}(p_X ||p_Y) \\
&= H(X|Y) +I(X;Y) + D_{KL}(p_X ||p_Y) \\
&= H(X|Y) +D_{KL}(p_{X,Y} ||  p_X p_Y) + D_{KL}(p_X ||p_Y)
\end{align}$$

but I doubt that this could be useful or have a nice interpretation.

You can readily conclude that $$H_X(Y)\ge H(X|Y)$$

with $H_X(Y) = H(X|Y) \iff$ $X,Y$ are iid.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional entropy is probably best viewed as the difference between two cross entropies: $H(Y|X) = H_{(X,Y)}(X,Y)-H_X(X)$. That is, it’s the incremental entropy from the probability given by X to that given by the joint variable (X,Y).